# Android: Triggering the onCreateOptionsMenu

Tags: android

How can I trigger the Android onCreateOptionsMenu function in my code, that is without the user clicking on the options menu button on their phone?

Comment: You probably don't want to do that. Maybe if you add more details on what you are trying to accomplish someone can help you with the correct way of doing what you need to do.

Answer (score 10):

`Activity.openOptionsMenu();` does the trick

Comment: it sounded like he wanted to know about `invalidateOptionsMenu()` so that it gets recreated.

Answer (score -2):

Call it yourself, such as in `onCreate()`. There is a problem though, you won't be able to pass the options menu because the parent Activity does not make it accessible.